# Vuejs + Laravel API: is it okay to store secret inside Vue SPA for authentication?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, vuejs2, axios, laravel-passport

I've created Vue SPA that consumes Laravel API for server-side operations, and each project lives in its separate folder.

Now, both projects are up and running and they are able to communicate to each other. I'm able to send HTTP requests using Axios from Vue app to Laravel API middleware routes.

I have hard-coded client secret into my Vue application and therefore everything is working fine. I can submit login credentials and receive an access token from the server, which I then store on my localStorage.

The following is a request method from Vue application

```
    handleLoginForm () {
        const postData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            client_id: '2',
            client_secret: 'MySecretFromTheDataBase',
            username: this.login.email,
            password: this.login.password
        }
        axios.post('oauth/token', postData) 
            .then(response => {
                // some logic
            })
    }
```

The question is, how do I have to handle the client_id and client_secret from within the client app? I suspect that having a hard-coded secret pose great security risk.

Which authentication method I should use?

Comment: Typically client secrets are not used for single page applications because, like you said they can't be secured.  For SPAs you'll usually use an [implicit grant](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#implicit-grant-tokens).